# Solution for graphing application events metrics in real time

Tags: metrics, graph

We have an application that parses tweets and we want to see the activity in real time. We have tried several solution without success. Our main problems is that the graphing solution (example:graphite), needs a continious flow of metrics. When the db aggregates the metrics it's an average operation which is done, not a a sum.

We recently saw cube from [square](https://github.com/square/cube) which would fit our requirement but it's too new.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Stack Overflow?